# Combination and Permutation again

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need some help with the following GRE Practice Question:

A reading list for a humanities course consists of $10$ books, of which $4$ are biographies and the rest $6$ are novels. Each student is required to read a selection of $4$ books from the list, including *$2$ or more biographies*.

How many selections of $4$ books satisfy the requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's note the possible types of solutions:
 - 4 biographies
 - 3 biographies and a novel
 - 2 biographies and a novel

For 4 biographies we have to choose 4 biographies from 4, or ${4 \choose 4}$. There is obviously only 1 way to do this.
For 3 biographies and a novel we have to choose 3 biographies from the 4, and 1 novel from the 6 or ${4 \choose 3} {6 \choose 1}=(4*6)=24$ 
For 2 biographies and a novel we have to choose 2 biographies from the 4, and 2 novels from the 6, or ${4 \choose 2} {6 \choose 2}=(4*3*6*5)/4=90$

So there are a total of $115$ different lists that satisfy the requirements.

Comment: The answer is actually 115.

Comment: thanks, corrected the algebra errors

Answer (score 2):

Method 1, direct:  $${4\choose 2}{6\choose 2}+{4\choose 3}{6\choose 1}+{4\choose 4}{6\choose 0}$$

Method 2, indirect: $${10\choose 4} - \Bigg( {4\choose 1}{6\choose 3} + {4\choose 0}{6\choose 4}\Bigg)$$

Comment: This gives the right answer. Thanks.